# Resolver problema con generador de contraseñas en C

Tags: c, programación-bajo-nivel

Me gustaría saber si alguien ayudarme a completar lo que me queda de este programa que lo que va a hacer es mediante consola de comandos (cmd) nombraremos al archivo (en este caso se llama password) y seguido a esto especificaremos en consola lo que queremos que muestre: el número de caracteres que va a tener la contraseña poniendo (-1, -2, -3...) después si queremos que la contraseña sea solamente de letras minúsculas que lo especificaremos con: -n, si son mayúsculas con: -M, si es de números con: -d y luego si queremos utilizar varios de estos al mismo tiempo sería simplemente combinándolos, y si queremos que sea con todos los parámetros con -all.

EJEMPLO: Contraseña de 9 caracteres con letras minúsculas y mayúsculas, y además, caracteres especiales: password -9 -Mn -c. Por cierto, al final también me gustaría añadir una función de error, que ya la tengo declarada al principio para que cuando el usuario coloque un parámetro que no existe, que le avise y mediante un printf() le avise de ello, aunque esto es relativamente fácil.

Código que llevo hecho:

**password.c**

```
/* Generador de contraseñas por consola -l -Mn -nM -all */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

void numeros(int);
void letras(int);
void mayusculas(int);
void minusculas(int);
void letrastodo(int); //Mayúsuculas y minúsculas
void especiales(int);
void mayusnumeros(int);
void minusnumeros(int);
void mayusminusnumeros(int);
void todo(int); //Todo lo del programa (números, letras...)

void error (void); //Si no seleccionas alguno de los parámetros (función error)

char contrasenia[500]; //Se almacena la contraseña con 500 caracteres
char mayus[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char minus[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char nums[] = "0123456789";
char caracteres[] = "!@#$^&*?";

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int longitud;
    char opcion[4];
    char item[4];
    sscanf(argv[1], "%c", item);
    
    if (strcmp(item, "H")==0 || strcmp (item, "H")==0) error();
    scanf(argv[2], "%c", opcion);
    
    longitud = atoi(item);
if (longitud==0) printf("La longitud no puede ser 0.");



if (argc==3){
    
    
    if (longitud < 5 || longitud < 66){
        
            if ((strcmp(opcion, "all"))==0) todo(longitud);
    if ((strcmp(opcion, "M"))==0) mayusculas(longitud);
    if ((strcmp(opcion, "n"))==0) minusculas(longitud);
    if ((strcmp(opcion, "d"))==0) numeros(longitud);
    if ((strcmp(opcion, "c"))==0) especiales(longitud);
    if ((strcmp(opcion, "Mn")==0) || (strcmp(opcion, "nM"))==0) letrastodo(longitud);
    if ((strcmp(opcion, "Md"))==0 || (strcmp(opcion, "dM"))==0) mayusnumeros(longitud);
    if ((strcmp(opcion, "md"))==0 || (strcmp(opcion, "dm"))==0) minusnumeros(longitud);
    if ((strcmp(opcion, "mdM")==0) || (strcmp(opcion, "mMd"))==0 || ((strcmp(opcion, "dmM")==0) || (strcmp(opcion, "Mmd"))==0))mayusminusnumeros(longitud);
    }
    else error();
}
else error();
}
```

Diría que me queda poco por hacer, ya que tengo lo que son las funciones y los ifs correctamente, pero lo que me quedaría sería si no me equivoco hacer las funciones de las propias letras, números, caracteres especiales... Para que se genere la propia contraseña, pero no se cómo hacerlo. Por cierto, si veis algún error no dudéis en corregírmelo, muchas gracias.

**EDIT 2:**

@Eferion Te digo más o menos en lo que he ido evolucionando respecto al código y los problemas que me han ido surgiendo...

En principio ya el código me llega a compilar y no tengo problemas en cuanto al IDE ni nada por el estilo ya que me he cambiado a Visual Studio Code, he hecho mis cambios en el código y ha llegar a compilar, el problema llega cuando al compilarlo a través de la consola de comandos da igual el parámetro que ponga y la longitud que va a tener la contraseña, que el programa me va a decir siempre lo mismo: "Clave no valida.Clave generada:" Os dejo una imagen para que lo podáis ver:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto al código en sí ahora mismo lo tengo así:

**passwordgenerator.c**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

/* Cada uno de los parámetros necesarios para utilizar en la consola*/

#define CARACTERES_ESPECIALES "!@#$^&*?"
int mayusculas = 0;
int minusculas = 0;
int digitos = 0;
int especiales = 0;

char opcion[6];

if (strcmp(opcion, "M") == 0){

    mayusculas = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "n") == 0){

    minusculas = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "d") == 0){

    digitos = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "Mn") == 0 || strcmp(opcion, "nM") == 0){

    mayusculas = 1;
    minusculas = 1;
}
else if ((strcmp(opcion, "mdM")==0) || (strcmp(opcion, "mMd"))==0 || ((strcmp(opcion, "dmM")==0) || (strcmp(opcion, "Mmd"))==0)){

    mayusculas = 1;
    minusculas = 1;
    digitos = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "all") == 0){

    mayusculas = 1;
    minusculas = 1;
    digitos = 1;
    especiales = 1;
}
else{
    printf("Clave no v%clida.", 160);
}

/*Creamos el alfabeto de todos los parámetros para luego hacer la contraseña libremente*/

int tam_alfabeto = 1; // Para finalizar la cadena - depuración
int longitud;
if (mayusculas) tam_alfabeto += 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
if (minusculas) tam_alfabeto += 'z' - 'a' + 1;
if (digitos)    tam_alfabeto += 10;
if (especiales) tam_alfabeto += strlen(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES);

char * alfabeto = (char*)malloc(tam_alfabeto * sizeof(char));
int index = 0;

for (char c='A'; c<='Z' && mayusculas; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (char c='a'; c<='z' && minusculas; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (char c='0'; c<='9' && digitos; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (int i=0; i<strlen(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES); i++)
    alfabeto[index++] = CARACTERES_ESPECIALES[i]; 

alfabeto[index] = 0; // Solo para fines de depuración

/*Generamos la contraseña*/

srand(time(NULL));

int clave_ok;
char*clave = (char*)malloc((longitud+1)*sizeof(char));
for( int i=0; i<longitud; i++)
{
    clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
}

clave[longitud] = 0; // Finalizamos la cadena

/*Hacemos una comprobación para que la contraseña tenga los parámetros que queremos*/

    do
    {
        for( int i=0; i<longitud; i++)
        {
            clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
        }
 
        int hay_mayusculas = 0;
        int hay_minusculas = 0;
        int hay_digitos    = 0;
        int hay_especiales = 0;
 
        for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++)
        {
            hay_mayusculas |= (clave[i] >= 'A' && clave[i] <= 'Z');
            hay_minusculas |= (clave[i] >= 'a' && clave[i] <= 'z');
            hay_digitos    |= (clave[i] >= '0' && clave[i] <= '9');
            hay_especiales |= (strchr(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES, clave[i]) != NULL);
        }
 
        clave_ok = 1;
        if (mayusculas) clave_ok &= hay_mayusculas;
        if (minusculas) clave_ok &= hay_minusculas;
        if (digitos)    clave_ok &= hay_digitos;
        if (especiales) clave_ok &= hay_especiales;
 
        if (!clave_ok)
        {
            printf("Clave no v%clida: %s\n", 160, clave);
        }
    } while (!clave_ok);
 
    printf("Clave generada: %s\n", clave);
    free(clave);
}
```

A parte del problema a la hora de compilar, que no me llega a salir la contraseña generada con los parámetros que le introduzco, la comprobación que me hace al finalizar el programa está bien, pero no hace falta que me diga realmente cuándo la contraseña que se ha generado no es válida y me lo muestre en la pantalla, simplemente quiero que me genere la contraseña definitiva con todos los parámetros que le he dicho, nada más.

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Respecto a tu nuevo problema, si te fijas en mi respuesta no he añadido el código que parsea los parámetros de entrada, luego `opcion` no está inicializada. De la misma manera, no has inicializado `longitud`, que es la variable que determina la longitud de la contraseña. Adicionalmente, cuando muestras el mensaje de _"Clave no válida"_, deberías cerrar la aplicación, no seguir ejecutando instrucciones

Comment: Debes entender el código que tienes entre manos y no limitarte a copiar y pegar. Si copias y pegas pierdes una oportunidad maravillosa de aprender

Comment: Perdona, pero es que lo del "parseo" es nuevo para mi y sinceramente no lo he usado en ningún programa. Pensaba que simplemente con un char y el numero de opciones iba a funcionar para trabajar con esa variable y el int para la longitud. Si me pudieses explicar un poco cómo funciona.

Comment: El código te tu pregunta le `argc` y `args` para leer los parámetros de entrada ... eso tienes que incorporarlo al código de mi respuesta

Comment: ¿No es lo que he escrito en int main --> (int argc, char *argv[])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución la has enfocado de una forma incorrecta. Tu programa va a ser larguísimo y con mucho código repetido.

El problema se puede resolver de forma más sencilla.

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un array con todos los carateres que se pueden usar, después generas una contraseña aleatoria utilizando ese array y, finalmente, compruebas que se ha añadido al menos un elemento de cada tipo. Si no encuentras un tipo de elemento puedes optar por generar una nueva contraseña.

Así, la primera parte sería saber qué alfabeto va a usar nuestra contraseña:

```
int mayusculas = 0;
int minusculas = 0;
int digitos = 0;
int especiales = 0;

if (strcmp(opcion, "M") == 0)
{
    mayusculas = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "n") == 0)
{
    minusculas = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "d") == 0)
{
    digitos = 1;
}
else if (strcmp(opcion, "Mn") == 0 || strcmp(opcion, "nM") == 0)
{
    mayusculas = 1;
    minusculas = 1;
}
// ...
else
{
    // Error, combinación no válida
}
```

El siguiente paso es componer el alfabeto propiamente dicho:

```
#define CARACTERES_ESPECIALES "!@#$^&*?"

int tam_alfabeto = 1; // Para finalizar la cadena - depuración
if (mayusculas) tam_alfabeto += 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
if (minusculas) tam_alfabeto += 'z' - 'a' + 1;
if (digitos)    tam_alfabeto += 10;
if (especiales) tam_alfabeto += strlen(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES);

char * alfabeto = (char*)malloc(tam_alfabeto * sizeof(char));
int index = 0;

for (char c='A'; c<='Z' && mayusculas; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (char c='a'; c<='z' && minusculas; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (char c='0'; c<='9' && digitos; c++)
    alfabeto[index++] = c;

for (int i=0; i<strlen(CARACTERES_ESPECIALES); i++)
    alfabeto[index++] = CARACTERES_ESPECIALES[i]; 

alfabeto[index] = 0; // Solo para fines de depuración
```

Ahora ya podemos generar la contraseña alegremente:

```
srand(time(NULL));

char*clave = (char*)malloc((longitud+1)*sizeof(char));
for( int i=0; i<longitud; i++)
{
    clave[i] = alfabeto[rand()%tam_alfabeto];
}

clave[longitud] = 0; // Finalizamos la cadena
```

Y ya solo queda comprobar que la clave cumple con los requisitos pedidos:

```
int hay_mayusculas = 0;
int hay_minusculas = 0;
int hay_digitos    = 0;
int hay_especiales = 0;

for (int i=0; i<longitud; i++)
{
    hay_mayusculas |= (clave[i] >= 'A' && clave[i] <= 'Z');
    hay_minusculas |= (clave[i] >= 'a' && clave[i] <= 'z');
    hay_digitos    |= (clave[i] >= '0' && clave[i] <= '9');
    hay_especiales |= (strchr(clave[i], CARACTERES_ESPECIALES) != NULL);
}

int clave_ok = 1;
if (mayusculas) clave_ok &= hay_mayusculas;
if (minusculas) clave_ok &= hay_minusculas;
if (digitos)    clave_ok &= hay_digitos;
if (especiales) clave_ok &= hay_especiales;

if (clave_ok)
{
    // Ya tienes la clave
}
else
{
    // Error, la clave no cumple los requisitos
}
```

Y no hay que complicarse más la vida duplicando código en diferentes funciones. Puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://ideone.com/Ogi3n4).

Comment: El problema es que al utilizar tu código, al parecer tengo errores de compilación y creo que se trata porque utilizo una versión de c distinta a la tuya. Hay cosas como el ciclo for cuando componemos el alfabeto en los que me da error. ¿Pongo una respuesta a mi post de los errores que me da? Ya que por comentario no lo puedo poner. Por cierto, utilizo Dev-C++

Comment: @Minibiru el problema es que estás usando una versión de C prehistórica. Te sugiero instalarte un compilador y un IDE más modernos

Comment: Ok, gracias por el dato. La verdad es que la explicación ha sido esplendida, dejo como resuelto el problema. Muchas gracias.